# perl, <Correct Input, grep

Tags: perl, grep

Please don't comment to say I already asked this, It's a logic question, I know it's mostly similar code but there are underlying syntax problems that I cannot decipher and have spent hours debugging this with no hope and I just really need this answered. And that other account was deleted so I did post this half an hour ago but can't view it. Please only comment if you want to help.

It should work everything is in data and it should be turning up results, i've had it working before so it must just be so syntax thing I'm not noticing. I can't get this work. I'm almost certain it's the grep statement.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
open ("data", "<text.txt") or die "Can't open";        #
        my @data = <data>;              #file looking into
        close "data";           #
while(<>){
        chomp;
        my $temp = $_;
        my ($name, $number, $expression) = split("\t", $temp);
        my $pattern = "\t";
        my @found = grep ( /(^$name$pattern\|$pattern$number$)/, @data );
        if(defined($found[0])){
                print $_;
                my ($what, $start, $stop, $chr, $who) = split("\t", $found[0]);
                print "\t", $chr, $start, $stop;
                @found = ();
        }
}
print "\n";
```

Input is of the format

```
A1B 1   68

A1C 299 0

A2B 547 0

A2L 877 30

A2M 2   7944
```

And this is the format of the data file

```
CLDN8   30214006    30216073    21  68

A1C  20808776    20811809    Y   

UBE2Q2P5Y   25431156    25437315    Y   

OR5M9   56462469    56463401    11  390162
```

I want to search for the instances of items in the first or second column of the input file in the data file which should match up with the first and 5th column(which may not exist) respectively

Expected output should be for this example

```
A1B 1   68 21 30214006    30216073
A1C 299 0 Y 20808776    20811809
```

But I'm getting nothing

Comment: If it were a syntax error, you'd get an error message when you attempt to run the program telling you that there's a syntax error. So, it's not a syntax error. You probably have a logic error, which is more difficult to detect.

Comment: Why is the pipe escaped in your regex? I don't see any pipe characters in either of your sample input files.

Comment: What are the approximate sizes of each file?

Comment: I should prob get rid of it, someone else told me to do that and @MattJacob you're right it's a logic error, sorry, but the the pipe didn't really fix it

Comment: update your code to match what you are trying now.  the grep regex only very vaguely looks like your input (but not enough to actually match).  Please also do answer the question about approximate sizes of each file.

Comment: about 20,000 lines for the input and 60,000 lines for the text file

Comment: @MattJacob: I suggested escaping the pipe in a comment on the OP's preceding question. That was before he showed any data, but his data does have pipes in earlier questions. Many people have tried hard to help this guy and failed

Comment: @Borodin No they did help! This is just after adjustments have been made and  other things are going wonky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* what you're looking for is this, but it's really very hard to tell because you have described your problem so poorly

I've had to make a lot of assumptions, but at least the output matches what you say you're expecting

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $data_file = 'text.txt';

my @data;
{
    open my $fh, '<', $data_file or die qq{Unable to open "$data_file" for input: $1};
    while ( <$fh> ) {
        next unless /\S/;
        push @data, [ split ];
    }
}

while ( <> ) {
    next unless /\S/;

    my ($name, $number, $expression) = split;

    for my $item ( @data ) {

        my ($what, $start, $stop, $chr, $who) = @$item;

        if ( $what eq $name or defined $who and $who eq $expression ) {
            print join("\t", $name, $number, $expression, $chr, $start, $stop), "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

#### output

```
A1B 1   68  21  30214006    30216073
A1C 299 0   Y   20808776    20811809
```

Comment: Thank-you So much!